# How can I install ubuntu restricted extras on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-restricted-extras

I want to install Ubuntu restricted extras on a PC without internet. I can download any setup files in another PC than install it in the PC without internet.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the .deb file by running `sudo apt-get download ubuntu-restricted-extras`. The file will be stored in your current directory or in `/var/cache/apt/archives` of your download machine if you ran `sudo apt-get install` instead. To install it on your offline Computer, just run `sudo dpkg -i` + path and/or file name (just double clicking the file should also work).